# Changing function execution order knocks app out of sync - node.js

Tags: node.js

I have this piece of code:

```
function asyncFunction (version, xmlConfig, resolve) {

  var xmlFileName = "/path/to/file/file.xml";
  fileService.generateXmlToFile(xmlFileName, xmlConfig, function(){

    runningService.startApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
      if (exitCode == 0) {
        console.log("App " + version + " started");

        multiJobService.runMultipleJobTypes(id, version, allJobsConfig, appDir, function(){
          runningService.stopApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
            if (exitCode == 0) {
              console.log("App " + version + " stopped");
              resolve();
            } else {
              console.log("App " + version + " failed to stop. Exit code " + exitCode);
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log("App " + version + " failed to start. Exit code " + exitCode);
      }

    });

   });
}
```

It starts one version of my app, runs through various tests, stops the app, starts the next version of the app, runs through the tests again then finally stops the app. Currently this works as expected.

Here are the startApp and stopApp functions:

```
startApp: function(appDir, version, callback) {

    console.log("App " + version + " starting...");

    var child = exec(
              config.env().path.scripts + "/appstart.sh " +
              appDir + " " + 
              version + " " + 
              "127.0.0.1" 
            );

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    child.on('close', function(code) {
      callback(code);
    });
  },

  stopApp: function(appDir, version, callback) {
    console.log("App " + version + " stopping...")

    var child = exec(
              config.env().path.scripts + "/appstop.sh " +
              appDir + " " + 
              version + " " 
            );

    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    child.on('close', function(code) {
      callback(code);
    });
  }
```

I want to add a few features to this. The first piece of this work is to ensure the app is stopped. For this I hoped to just swap the order the startApp and stopApp functions are called. This is my new code:

```
function asyncFunction (version, xmlConfig, resolve) {
  runningService.stopApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
    if (exitCode == 0) {
      console.log("App " + version + " stopped");
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("App " + version + " failed to stop. Exit code " + exitCode);
    }
  });
  var xmlFileName = "/path/to/file/file.xml";
  fileService.generateXmlToFile(xmlFileName, xmlConfig, function(){

    runningService.startApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
      if (exitCode == 0) {
        console.log("App " + version + " started");

        multiJobService.runMultipleJobTypes(id, version, allJobsConfig, appDir, function(){
        });
      } else {
        console.log("App " + version + " failed to start. Exit code " + exitCode);
      }

    });

  });
}
```

When I run it startApp begins before stopApp has completed. This causes errors where startApp fails because running app processes are detected. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed the stop app in the wrong place. when I moved the `});` of stopApp to after startApp my the application worked as desired. Here is my updated code:

```
function asyncFunction (version, xmlConfig, resolve) {
  runningService.stopApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
    if (exitCode == 0) {
      console.log("App " + version + " stopped");
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("App " + version + " failed to stop. Exit code " + exitCode);
    }
  var xmlFileName = "/path/to/file/file.xml";
  fileService.generateXmlToFile(xmlFileName, xmlConfig, function(){

    runningService.startApp(appDir, version, function(exitCode){
      if (exitCode == 0) {
        console.log("App " + version + " started");

        multiJobService.runMultipleJobTypes(id, version, allJobsConfig, appDir, function(){
        });
      } else {
        console.log("App " + version + " failed to start. Exit code " + exitCode);
      }

    });

  });
});
}
```